# Can I assign a type as if it was an int or a string

Tags: c#, declaration

Suppose I created a class `Number`. Is there a way I can assign a variable of this type the way I do with ints or strings?

```
Number n1 = 123;
Number n2 = "123";
```

I don't mind to have a constructor that deals with any of these declarations, as long as I can write like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you want to use can work if you declare an [implicit cast operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) like this:

```
public class Number
{
    public static implicit operator Number(int i) => /* create and return your Number instance */;

    //...
}
```

Now the assignment `Number n = 12;` will call this operator.

But use this with care, it might have side effects where the operator is called when you did not expect it.
Implicit cast operators should only be used when there is no information lost (hence there are implicit conversion from `int` to `double`, but only explicit conversions from `double` to `int`).

Comment: Do you think you can give me an example of the operator being called unexpectedly? I couldn't figure out one myself.

Comment: @Daniel Let's say you have two methods `WriteToLog(Number n)` and `WriteToLog(int i)`. You could for some reason delete the second one, but all your calls like`WriteToLog(12)` would still compile. That's of course a made-up example and I don't know the scenarios you want to use this for. I just wanted to say that there might be pit falls.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot overload the assignment operator `=` for user-defined types, such as your `Number` class. You can, however, use the constructor approach, **or** you can use a user-defined conversion operator. That looks like this:

```c#
public class Number
{
    private int _actualValue;

    public Number(int value) => _actualValue = value;

    // User defined conversion operators
    // From int
    public static implicit operator Number(int value)
        => new Number(value);

    // From string
    public static implicit operator Number(string value)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(value, out _actualValue))
        {
            // Invalid format, couldn't parse
            // Throw exception, or set _actualValue = 0
        }
    }
}
```

To use it:

```c#
// From int
Number number = (Number)123;

// From string
Number number = (Number)"123";

// You can exclude the explicit "(Number)" cast
```

More about user-defined conversion operations here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators

Comment: with _implicit_ operators, you don't need the _explicit_ cast anymore.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. Updated the answer with a comment in the code.